# scite not showing program output in a pop-up window ubuntu

Tags: io, lua, scite

I am running lua script via scite in Ubuntu 12.04. When I execute an `io.read` program.
example: (each command is on a separate line)

```
io.write("Please enter a number: ")
user_input = io.read()
print(user_input)
```

When I execute the program, I don't get a separate pop-up dialogue window asking for the user input.

I get, on the right hand side of the code, the following output:

```
> lua5.1 "io_examples.lua"
Please enter a number: nil
```

I know this may sound stupid, but how do I get the pop-up output window asking the the user's input?

Answer (score 0):

The nil returned by `io.read` could be a hint that an error has occurred during reading. You can check this by surrounding your io.read statement with an assert:

`local user_input = assert(io.read())`

or

`local user_input = assert(io.read("*number"))`.

My initial guess is that you received a: *bad file descriptor* caused because the standard input (`stdin`) is not set.

More information can be found here:

http://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html

http://www.lua.org/pil/8.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried both suggestions and here is what happened:io.write("Please enter a number: ")
local user_input = assert(io.read())
print(user_input)>lua5.1 "io_examples.lua"
lua5.1: io_examples.lua:2: assertion failed!
stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'assert'
 io_examples.lua:2: in main chunk
 [C]: ?
Please enter a number: >Exit code: 1

Comment: Both suggestions returned the same result:Thank you for the reply! I tried both suggestions and here is what happened for both:
>lua5.1 "io_examples.lua"
lua5.1: io_examples.lua:2: assertion failed!
stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'assert'
 io_examples.lua:2: in main chunk
 [C]: ?
Please enter a number: >Exit code: 1

Comment: My confusion is that the program is executing, but not allowing for the user to input anything. How do I make it so the program will wait and when the user actually enters a number, or whatever, the program will complete the execution? Is there another program I need to have installed besides scite to allow for the interactive window?

Answer (score 0):

How I finally got the program to execute correctly was from running it via ubuntu terminal. I simply had to cd to the directory where the program was located, then type "lua .
I didn't get the neat pop-up window, but the code executed correctly.